# Ruby Rails - NoMethodError , drop-down list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-views.htm). It has written in previous version of Rails and I am using Rails 4. There was a drop-down list the selection does not appear, I am getting following error:

```
NoMethodError in Book#show
Showing C:/Ruby193/mylibrary/app/views/book/show.html where line #3 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):

 1 <h1><%= @book.title %></h1>
 2 <p><strong>Price: </strong> $<%= @book.price %><br />
 3 <strong>Subject: </strong> <%= @subject.name %><br />
 4 </p>
 5 <p><%= @book.description %></p>
 6 <hr />

Rails.root: C:/Ruby193/mylibrary
```

Here is the show.html

```
  <h1><%= @book.title %></h1>
    <p><strong>Price: </strong> $<%= @book.price %><br />
    <strong>Subject: </strong> <%= @book.subject.name %><br />
    </p>
    <p><%= @book.description %></p>
    <hr />
    <%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

Here is migrate/258412_subjects.rb

```
class Subjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
      create_table :subjects do |t|
       t.column :name, :string
    end
    Subject.create :name => "Physics"
    Subject.create :name => "Mathematics"
    Subject.create :name => "Chemistry"
    Subject.create :name => "Psychology"
    Subject.create :name => "Geography"
  end

  def self.down
      drop_table :subjects
  end
end
```

Here is migrate/05465_books.rb

```
class Books < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
     create_table :books do |t|
    t.column :title, :string, :limit => 32, :null => false
    t.column :price, :float
    t.column :subject_id, :integer
    t.column :description, :text
     end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :books
  end
end
```

Here is models/book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subject
    validates_presence_of :title
    validates_numericality_of :price, :message=>"Error Message"
end
```

Here is my controller class book_controller.rb

```
class BookController < ApplicationController

  def list
    @books = Book.all
  end
  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @book = Book.new
    @subjects = Subject.all
  end
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save!
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
      @subjects = Subject.all
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @subjects = Subject.all
  end
  def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
    else
      @subjects = Subject.all
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
  def delete
    Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :action => 'list'
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.permit(:title, :price, :description)
  end

end
```

What should I do?, Thank you in advance

Comment: @subject is most likely undefined in your view.  What does your controller look like? Also try restarting your server (the error and the view seem to disagree on the content of the line in question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write

```
@book.subject.name
```

Of course then you should test if the `subject` is set. One way to do that is to write

```
@book.subject.try(:name)
```

This will will try `name` if `subject` is not nil.

And a general remark: do not seed the database from within a migration. Normally you will migrate only once, but when you go to production or on test, you will run `rake db:setup` which will create the database schema without running the migrations.

Instead use `db/seed.rb` to seed the database. This is then a repeatable process, which will also be needed when running the tests (which start from a clean/empty database).

Comment: I would even argue that the subjects should be a constant or class method belonging to the Book class

Comment: Thank you so much, This way has solved my problem, I dont take error but the selection still does not appear

Answer (score 0):

According to your error

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

```
Extracted source (around line #3):

 1 <h1><%= @book.title %></h1>
 2 <p><strong>Price: </strong> $<%= @book.price %><br />
 3 <strong>Subject: </strong> <%= @subject.name %><br />
```

@subject is nil in your show.
Since your controller has

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

for your show, it seems likely that this is the case.

The code you have posted for your show, however, has the line as

```
<strong>Subject: </strong> <%= @book.subject.name %><br />
```

I would advise you to try restarting your server, as it seems to have cached an older version of your view.